# why my subdomain is not accessible from the Internet?

Tags: centos, apache-virtualhost

I am using virtualhost in Centos 6.6.

This is my conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.mydomain.ca
    ServerAlias test.mydomain.ca
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test_mydomain/public_html
    <Directory "/var/www/test_mydomain/public_html">
        allow from all
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/www/test_mydomain/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/test_mydomain/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and this is my hosts file:

```
IPADDRESS test.mydomain.ca
```

I am able to see index of my subdomain in the server. However, when I try this in another computer, I get the error: unable to load. Why?

This is the output of apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS

```
_default_:443          myipaddress (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:74)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server test.mydomain.ca (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:993)
         port 80 namevhost test.mydomain.ca (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:993)
                 alias test.mydomain.ca
```

Comment: What other `VirtualHost` stanzas are configured on your server? What's the exact error message on that other computer? (I presume something about a failed name resolution, since you had to add an entry to the hosts file on your local system.)

Comment: There's no any other virtualhost in my conf file. the error is unable to connect.

Comment: If there is only one `VirtualHost` configured, Apache should select it as the default one and serve the correct directory. Can you post the output of `apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS`?

Comment: VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
_default_:443          myipaddress (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:74)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server test.mydomain.ca (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:993)
         port 80 namevhost test.mydomain.ca (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:993)
                 alias test.mydomain.ca

Comment: Please [add that to your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/181402/edit) — that way, it's far more legible than as a comment. ;)

Comment: i did =) looks better

Comment: Strange. Your `VirtualHost` *is* the default one, so you should see the index of `/var/www/test_mydomain/public_html` when you navigate to `http://test.mydomain.ca/`… Do you at least get log entries in `/var/www/test_mydomain/requests.log` for your connection attempts?

Comment: Oh, I somehow read a "not" in "I am able to see index of my subdomain in the server." and assumed your `VirtualHost` didn't work as intended… My mistake, sorry. :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it has to do with DNS.  You said that `IPADDRESS test.mydomain.ca` is in your hosts file.  Have you also added it to the hosts file of that second computer?  Or have you added it to a public DNS server?

If you have done one of those things, and you still can't reach it, there are a couple of things that could cause that:

- A firewall is blocking the inbound connection.
- You second computer is not in the same network, and your IP Address is in RFC 1918 address space (e.g: 172.16-31.x.x, 10.x.x.x, 192.168.x.x).  This address space is not route-able over the internet.

I would start there and see what you can find out.  `ping` and `traceroute` are your friends here.

Comment: yeap my second computer is not in the same network with server. My ip starts with 104. But I didn't add IPADDRESS test.mydomain.ca in my second computer.

Comment: when I ping test.mydomain.ca, I see the IP address of my server. I think that means there's no firewall.

Comment: That you can see the IP address of your server when you ping it only means that DNS is configured correctly. There can still be a firewall that's blocking connections to the webserver, and the error message "unable to connect" suggests that there is one (although it could still be a misconfiguration of the webserver that causes it to block connections from some IPs, or to bind to the wrong interface or IP).

Comment: It was firewall. I closed it and restarted apache. It works